# Django not Letting Creating a Project

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and just now I tried to create a new project, however every time I type in the command line "django-admin.py startproject testproject" it keeps giving me all the options for the django-admin file. I have tried everything but it only keeps opening this menu. My guess is that it is something to do with environment variables. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: I don't imagine it would work any better, but perhaps you could try using `C:\Python27\python.exe C:\django\bin\django-admin.py startproject examplesite`? (obviously changing the paths to wherever `python.exe` and `django-admin.py` are)

Comment: icktoofay, thank you! That did it! Do you have any idea why? This also worked: "python c:\python33\scripts\django-admin.py startproject examplesite"

Could it be because the script was trying to execute itself without the interpreter?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why that works, but I've posted it along with a *plausible* explanation as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try prefixing it with Python:

```
python C:\Python33\scripts\django-admin.py startproject examplesite
```

I admit I'm not entirely sure what's going on here, but I suspect Windows thought you wanted to open `django-admin.py` as an ordinary document. Most documents can't really take arguments, so Windows may have discarded them. `python` is a normal executable and can take arguments, so it works. <sub><sup>Again, disclaimer: I have no idea what's actually happening there; that was just a guess.</sup></sub>